# How to map multiple columns in a dataframe based on the value of "key" column using numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, vectorization

Running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'key': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key1', 'key2'],
    'colA': ['value1A', 'value2A', 'value3A', 'value4A', 'value5A'],
    'colB': ['value1B', 'value2B', 'value3B', 'value4B', 'value5B'],
    'colC': ['value1C', 'value2C', 'value3C', 'value4C', 'value5C'],
    'colD': ['value1D', 'value2D', 'value3D', 'value4D', 'value5D']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create conditions
conditions = [df['key'] == 'key1',
            df['key'] == 'key2',
            df['key'] == 'key3']

# Apply conditions and choices to the respective columns
df['colA'] = np.select([df['key'] == 'key1'], [df['colA']], default= 'NA')
df['colD'] = np.select([df['key'] == 'key1'], [df['colD']], default= 'NA')
df['colB'] = np.select([df['key'] == 'key2'], [df['colB']], default= 'NA')
df['colC'] = np.select([df['key'] == 'key3'], [df['colC']], default= 'NA')

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Produces this:

```
         key     colA     colB     colC     colD
0  key1  value1A       NA       NA  value1D
1  key2       NA  value2B       NA       NA
2  key3       NA       NA  value3C       NA
3  key1  value4A       NA       NA  value4D
4  key2       NA  value5B       NA       NA
```

Is there a way to rewrite this efficiently so I don't have to do numpy.select for each column I want to map? The "key" column essentially determines which columns contain valid data for that particular row. If the data is invalid I want to mark it as NA, if it is valid I want to keep the value that's in the row. In my real dataset, the "key" column controls how I would map more than one column like how key1 controls the mapping to colA and colD above. I prefer to use numpy or other vectorized methods as from what I understand it is faster than other methods such as map but I'm open to hearing any and all ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a mask in a vectorial way with a dictionary of the key/columns, [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and use it to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the unwanted values:

```
d = {'key1': ['colA', 'colD'],
     'key2': ['colB'],
     'key3': ['colC'],
    }

s = pd.Series(d).explode()
mask = pd.get_dummies(s, dtype=bool).groupby(level=0).max()

cols = df.columns.difference(['key'])

df[cols] = df[cols].where(mask.reindex(df['key']).to_numpy(), 'NA')
```

Output:

```
    key     colA     colB     colC     colD
0  key1  value1A       NA       NA  value1D
1  key2       NA  value2B       NA       NA
2  key3       NA       NA  value3C       NA
3  key1  value4A       NA       NA  value4D
4  key2       NA  value5B       NA       NA
```

Intermediates:

```
# mask
       colA   colB   colC   colD
key1   True  False  False   True
key2  False   True  False  False
key3  False  False   True  False

# mask.reindex(df['key']).to_numpy()
[[ True False False  True]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False  True False]
 [ True False False  True]
 [False  True False False]]
```

---

Another approach could be to use reshaping of your data, filtering with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
d = {'key1': ['colA', 'colD'],
     'key2': ['colB'],
     'key3': ['colC'],
    }

(df.reset_index()
   .melt(['index', 'key'])
   .merge(pd.Series(d).explode().rename_axis('key')
            .reset_index(name='variable'))
   .set_index(['index', 'key', 'variable'])['value']
   .unstack('variable', fill_value='NA')
   .reset_index('key').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating on the columns can be efficient, since operation is on the whole columns, and not the rows. Ultimately, you'll need to test it on your data, especially as the size increases:

```py
mapping = {'key1':['colA','colD'],'key2':'colB','key3':'colC'}
new_df = df.copy()
for key, value in mapping.items():
    out = df.loc[:, value]
    out = out.where(df['key']==key, 'NA')
    new_df.loc[:, value] = out

print(new_df)
    key     colA     colB     colC     colD
0  key1  value1A       NA       NA  value1D
1  key2       NA  value2B       NA       NA
2  key3       NA       NA  value3C       NA
3  key1  value4A       NA       NA  value4D
4  key2       NA  value5B       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace the locations that don't have the correct column, key combination. I stored the combinations in a dictionary and looped through them. While loops are not very efficient, assuming you don't have a ton of columns/keys, it should be plenty fast enough and (more importantly) readable.

```py
mappings = {"key1":["colA", "colD"], "key2":["colB"], "key3":["colC"]}
for key, cols in mappings.items():
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df.where(df["key"] == key)[col]
```

Result:

```
    key     colA     colB     colC     colD
0  key1  value1A      NaN      NaN  value1D
1  key2      NaN  value2B      NaN      NaN
2  key3      NaN      NaN  value3C      NaN
3  key1  value4A      NaN      NaN  value4D
4  key2      NaN  value5B      NaN      NaN
```

If it's important to have `"NA"` instead of `NaN`, you can add that to the `df.where` call.

```py
mappings = {"key1":["colA", "colD"], "key2":["colB"], "key3":["colC"]}
for key, cols in mappings.items():
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df.where(df["key"] == key, "NA")[col]
```

Result:

```
    key     colA     colB     colC     colD
0  key1  value1A       NA       NA  value1D
1  key2       NA  value2B       NA       NA
2  key3       NA       NA  value3C       NA
3  key1  value4A       NA       NA  value4D
4  key2       NA  value5B       NA       NA
```

Comment: That's a **nested loop**, so *in fine* you're looping over all sub blocks with python loops.

Comment: @mozway Yes, it is order `N_keys x N_cols`. I'd argue that is fine when those numbers are small. As I said, I'm trading speed for readability. I'll leave it to OP to decide which is more important for their specific case.

Comment: I agree with you if the number is really small, then having a loop is similar to using a few select, but I commented since OP clearly stated that a vectorized/efficient method is needed ("*Is there a way to rewrite this efficiently*" / "*I prefer to use numpy or other vectorized methods as from what I understand it is faster […]*")

Comment: @mozway Ah, that is true.

Comment: @jared, just noticed your code. If it is ok with you, i'll delete mine and update yours. The nested loop is not necessary and should still be performant

Comment: @sammywemmy What do you think should be changed? The only differences between yours and mine is that you operate on a new data frame and you use `loc`.

Comment: No need for the second loop, a single loop is fine. Pass the heavy lifting to the dataframe

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right.